# How to return a Mongoid::Criteria for A has many B has many C relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Relations are:

```
Account has many Groups
Group has many Users
```

I need a method in Account to get all users (Users of each group) and then apply an User scope:

```
account.rb
def users
  self.groups.map(&:users).flatten # Cannot apply User's scope
end

user.rb
scope :foo, ->{ where(bar: 'baz' }
```

I think I have to return a Mongoid::Criteria in `def users` instead of an Array, so I can do `account.users.foo`. How can I do that?

Thanks!

PS: I tried (that should work in ActiveRecord):

```
def users
  ids=self.groups.map(&:users).flatten.map(&:id)
  User.where(id: ids)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def users
  User.where(:group_id.in => self.groups.map(&:id))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def users
  self.groups.map {|g| g.users.foo }.flatten
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I have several scopes, not only `foo`.

Comment: you can chain them : `g.users.foo.bar`

Answer (score 0):

I use `find` instead of `where` and it works.

```
def users
  ids=self.groups.map(&:users).flatten.map(&:id)
  User.find(ids)
end
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what I want. Suggestion will be appreciated.